# Conflicts created by two same html5lib packages installed by pip and anaconda

Tags: python, error-handling, pip, anaconda, html5lib

I have two html5lib. And it makes errors when I try to update to tensorflow.

Here is the two html5lib shown by `conda list`

`html5lib                  1.0.1                    py36_0
html5lib                  0.9999999                 <pip>`

The problem is that I cannot remove or update it.

> When I use `pip install html5lib`, an error pops up

`Requirement already satisfied: html5lib in /Users/apple/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages (1.0.1)
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/apple/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_internal/basecommand.py", line 228, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/Users/apple/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_internal/commands/install.py", line 291, in run
    resolver.resolve(requirement_set)
  File "/Users/apple/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolve.py", line 103, in resolve
    self._resolve_one(requirement_set, req)
  File "/Users/apple/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolve.py", line 262, in _resolve_one
    check_dist_requires_python(dist)
  File "/Users/apple/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_internal/utils/packaging.py", line 46, in check_dist_requires_python
    feed_parser.feed(metadata)
  File "/Users/apple/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/email/feedparser.py", line 175, in feed
    self._input.push(data)
  File "/Users/apple/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/email/feedparser.py", line 103, in push
    self._partial.write(data)
TypeError: string argument expected, got 'NoneType'`

> But when I use `pip uninstall html5lib`, another error pops up

`Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/apple/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_internal/basecommand.py", line 228, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/Users/apple/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_internal/commands/uninstall.py", line 68, in run
    auto_confirm=options.yes, verbose=self.verbosity > 0,
  File "/Users/apple/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_internal/req/req_install.py", line 660, in uninstall
    uninstalled_pathset = UninstallPathSet.from_dist(dist)
  File "/Users/apple/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_internal/req/req_uninstall.py", line 355, in from_dist
    for path in uninstallation_paths(dist):
  File "/Users/apple/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_internal/req/req_uninstall.py", line 50, in unique
    for item in fn(*args, **kw):
  File "/Users/apple/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_internal/req/req_uninstall.py", line 67, in uninstallation_paths
    r = csv.reader(FakeFile(dist.get_metadata_lines('RECORD')))
  File "/Users/apple/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1408, in get_metadata_lines
    return yield_lines(self.get_metadata(name))
  File "/Users/apple/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1404, in get_metadata
    value = self._get(self._fn(self.egg_info, name))
  File "/Users/apple/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1516, in _get
    with open(path, 'rb') as stream:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Users/apple/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/html5lib-1.0.1.dist-info/RECORD'`

Any ideas to fix this problem?

Comment: why not create a new virtual environment that doesn't have html5lib initially, u can install later

Comment: Well, I found it troublesome to have many virtual environments.       The problem is now solved(or dismissed). I have copy the missing file from ~/python3.6/site-packages/html5lib-0.9999999.dist-info/ to ~/python3.6/site-packages/html5lib-1.0.1.dist-info/